# error handling in Rabbitmq RPC model nestjs with RPCException

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, nestjs, microservices, rpc

I have 2 services, one producer and another one consumer. i created an RPCException in consumer to test it.when the producer service sending a RPC message to consumer and consumer service throw a RPCException, i expected an object with error message in result of rpc request from producer service, but i got empty object {}. my problem is that response message from consumer is empty object but i expected an object with error code or error message.

producer main.ts:

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { ApiGatewayConfigService } from './api-gateway.config.service';
import { ApiGatewayModule } from './api-gateway.module';
import * as sourceMapSupport from 'source-map-support';
import { DocumentBuilder, SwaggerModule } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
import { FastifyAdapter, NestFastifyApplication } from '@nestjs/platform-fastify';
import { ExceptionFilter } from '@shared/shared/rpc-exception.filter';

async function bootstrap() {
  sourceMapSupport.install();
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(
    ApiGatewayModule,
    new FastifyAdapter()
  );

  const configService = app.get(ApiGatewayConfigService);

  app.useGlobalFilters(new ExceptionFilter());
  app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      transform: true,
      transformOptions: {
        enableImplicitConversion: true
      },
      whitelist: true,
      forbidNonWhitelisted: true,
      disableErrorMessages: configService.APP_ENVIRONMENT === 'production'
    })
  );
  app.enableShutdownHooks();
  await app.listen(configService.APP_LISTENING_PORT, '0.0.0.0');
}
bootstrap();
```

producer service:

```
  async page(privileges: UserPrivileges, acceptLanguage: string): Promise<any> {

      const result = await this.amqpConnection.request<any>({
        exchange: process.env.API_GATEWAY_RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE_NAME,
        routingKey: 'trend_specific_test',
        payload: {
          options:{
            from: 0,
            limit: 21,
            privileges
          },
          acceptLanguage
        },
      });

      console.log(result);
  }
```

consumer service:

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { TrendModule } from './trend.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.createApplicationContext(TrendModule);
}
bootstrap();
```

consumer service:

```
    @UseFilters(new ExceptionFilter())
    @RabbitRPC({
        exchange: RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE_NAME,
        routingKey: 'trend_specific_test',
        queue: 'trend_specific_test',
        allowNonJsonMessages: true,
    })
    async dailyPlaylists(msg: {options: SearchOptions, acceptLanguage: string}): Promise<any> {
        return this.trendDataService.testMethod(msg.options, msg.acceptLanguage);
    }
```

consumer data service:

```
  async testMethod(options: SearchOptions, acceptLanguage: string): Promise<any> {
    throw new RpcException('Invalid credentials.');
}
```

rpc-exception.filter.ts

```
import { Catch, RpcExceptionFilter, ArgumentsHost } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { RpcException } from '@nestjs/microservices';

@Catch(RpcException)
export class ExceptionFilter implements RpcExceptionFilter<RpcException> {
  catch(exception: RpcException, host: ArgumentsHost): Observable<any> {
    return throwError(() => exception.getError());
  }
}
```